# What is meant by common distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is meant by Common density/distribution function, I see the term being used many places but couldn't find a explanation.

For Eg. In the below question

> assuming that X<sub>1</sub>,...,X<sub>n</sub> are independent with common density function f,
>
> establish that the joint distribution of X<sup>(1)</sup>,...,X<sup>(n)</sup> is given by
>
> f<sub>X(1),...,X(n)</sub> (x1,...,xn) = n!f(x<sub>1</sub>) ... f(x<sub>n</sub>)     ,     x<sub>1</sub> < x<sub>2</sub> <··· ··· < x<sub>n</sub>,
> and f<sub>X(1),...,X(n)</sub> (x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) = 0, otherwise.

Comment: I think it simply means f is the density function for all your variables.

Comment: 'independent with common density' is the same as 'i.i.d.'